# Applying GroupBy Filter in AngularJS View

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on my first AngularJS project which is an example from Adam Freeman's book "Pro AngularJS".  I'm trying to apply a groupBy filter in my view and I just can't seem to get it to work.  Here is my view where you can see I'm just trying to group by name:

```
<div ng-controller="ordersCtrl">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>City</th><th>Value</th><th></th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="order in orders">
        <td>{{order.name}}</td>
        <td>{{order.city}}</td>
        <td>{{calcTotal(order) | currency}}</td>
        <td>
            <button ng-click="selectOrder(order)" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
                Details
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div ng-show="selectedOrder">
    <h3>Order Details</h3>

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Count</th><th>Price</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in selectedOrder.products | groupBy:['name']">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.count}}</td>
            <td>{{item.price | currency}} </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I injected "$filter" into the "ordersCtrl" controller.  When I do this I get "Unknown provider: groupByFilterProvider <- groupByFilter".  The "ordersCtrl" controller is in the Angular module "sportsStoreAdmin".  I don't understand what is required to get this to work properly.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: groupBy is not built in filter are you defining this filter ?

Comment: you could use this module: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

Comment: can you please create a fiddle for this ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others

`orderBy` is available out of the box, but not `groupBy`.

Please include [angular filter module](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

You can refer [this](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby).

Answer (score 0):

Varun/Moncef Hassein-Bey . . thanks for responding . . . still missing something . . . Here are some more details . . .

So I'm trying to apply the groupBy filter in a div that is under the controller "ordersCtrl".  The "ordersCtrl" controller is defined a module called "sportsStoreAdmin" which is orignally defined elsewhere.
The creation of the original "sportsStoreAdmin" module looks like this:

angular.module("sportsStoreAdmin", ["ngRoute", "ngResource"])

In the original "sportsStoreAdmin" I am referencing angular-filters.min.js in a script tag in the head section.

When I do this I'm still getting "Unknown provider: groupByFilterProvider <- groupByFilter"

So apparently I'm still missing something here.

Pete